# How install GraphicsMagick with quantum 16

Tags: apt, configuration, imagemagick

How can I configure GraphicsMagick to use `--with-quantum-depth=16` before installing it with `apt-get`? Is it possible to do or should I build it from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build it from source (you should make sure that your `deb-src` lines in your `sources.list` are activated, and you ran `sudo apt-get update`):

```
mkdir src && cd src && apt-get source graphicsmagick
```

Enter the *graphicsmagick-** directory. Now, run `vim debian/rules` (if you want to use another text editor, be my guest) and look for the line that reads:

> ./configure $(gm_confflags) \

bellow this add (you need to press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert) `--with-quantum-depth=16 \` so it should more or less looks like:

```
    CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" CXXFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)" \
        ./configure $(gm_confflags) \
            --with-quantum-depth=16 \
            --enable-shared \
            --enable-static \
            --enable-libtool-verbose \
            --prefix=/usr \
            --mandir=\$${prefix}/share/man \
            --infodir=\$${prefix}/share/info \
            --docdir=\$${prefix}/share/doc/graphicsmagick \
            --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts \
            --with-x \
            --x-includes=/usr/include/X11 \
            --x-libraries=/usr/lib/X11 \
            --without-dps \
            --without-modules \
            --without-frozenpaths \
            --with-perl \
            --with-perl-options="INSTALLDIRS=vendor"
```

Save the file (press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then type `:wq` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep graphicsmagick
dpkg-buildpackage
sudo dpkg -i ../graphicsmagick*.deb
```

The first one installs the build dependencies, the second builds the package, the third installs the packages. And thats it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the approach suggested in the answer but it does not work.  After some analysis I realized that it makes the package and installs it, but it does not change the library itself.

i.e. `/usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick++.so.3.6.2` has the original package build date, and octave goes on saying:

```
warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits per pixel
```

Therefore I issued the command `make install` from the directory
`graphicsmagick-1.3.18/` and this changes the library. As a consequence octave does not work properly anymore: running `imgread` some symbol can not be found.

In order to put it back to work you have to run `apt-get build-dep octave`, obtain octave sources, run `./configure`, compile, and install. Then you get:

```
warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 16 bits per pixel
```

This is not an orthodox approach for sure, but if you really need 16 bits per pixel, it works.

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the same issue with `imread`. Can you please help me - from which directory to run the `./configure`? Thanks.

Comment: For Octave users who just want to suppress the GraphicsMagick warning (and are not actually using 16-bit images), the following command will do the job: `warning('off', 'Octave:GraphicsMagic-Quantum-Depth');`. See [this bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45662) for the reference about the warning ID, and [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Enabling-and-Disabling-Warnings.html) for how to disable warnings.